# Cleanest way to copy part of one directory to another

Tags: performance-tuning, files-and-directories

I often want to copy a directory and clean it up for deployment purposes. This may involve pruning out large datasets, cleaning up private junk, etc. Doesn't really matter.

The issue I often run into is that this is very, very slow, and very, very wasteful when the things I want to prune out contribute the vast majority of my directory size (e.g. a .git folder or test data).

A better approach, therefore, would be to only copy the relevant parts of the directory over, but I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be. The naive way would just be to call `CopyFile` on every single file I want to copy, but that seems rather wasteful as `CopyFile` can't operate in batch.

My thought was to basically do the following:

- Figure out my total set files in the dir (can be slow, but only like .2s slow on every very large dirs)
- Determine which of these files I truly want to copy (if the method can be done without step one, jump here)
- Figure out the total byte size of all the complement of these. If huge, use a method based on `CopyFile` and `CopyDirectory`. If small, use one `CopyDirectory` and prune with `DeleteFile` and `DeleteDirectory`.

There's also a question of how to optimize the number of `CopyFile`/`DeleteFile` and `CopyDirectory`/`DeleteDirectory` calls to make, but I think I can answer that one by determining which folders are copied/deleted wholesale and which ones have only portions copied/deleted.

Honestly, though, it seems like this should be easier that it appears to be. Does it have to be so annoying?

Comment: Not a _Mathematica_ solution, but you may be interested in `rsync` (possibly with `--delete`) for solving the file transfer problem once you know the set of files you want to transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I've been doing it:

```
(* ::Section:: *)
(*FileTools*)
BeginPackage["FileSystemTools`"]
PartialDirectoryCopy::usage="";
CopyDirectoryFiles::usage="";
PruneDirectoryFiles::usage="";
Begin["`Private`"];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PartialDirectoryCopy*)
Options[PartialDirectoryCopy]=
  {
    "RemovePaths"->{},
    "RemovePatterns"->{},
    "ModeSwitchByteCount"->5*10^6
    };
PartialDirectoryCopy[src_, targ_, ops:OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Module[
    {
      rempaths=
        Select[
          Flatten@{OptionValue["RemovePaths"]},
          StringPattern`StringPatternQ
          ],
      rempatts=
        Select[
          Flatten@{OptionValue["RemovePatterns"]},
          StringPattern`StringPatternQ
          ],
      fullFNames,
      fileBytesTotal,
      remFiles,
      restFiles
      },
    If[Length@Join[rempaths, rempatts]>0,
      fullFNames=FileNames["*", src, \[Infinity]];
      remFiles=
        Join[
          FileNames[rempaths, src],
          FileNames[rempatts, src, \[Infinity]]
          ];
      restFiles=
        Select[
          Complement[fullFNames, remFiles],
          Not@*StringStartsQ[Alternatives@@remFiles]
          ];
      fileBytesTotal=
        Total[FileByteCount/@Select[remFiles, Not@*DirectoryQ]];
      Quiet@DeleteDirectory[targ, DeleteContents->True];
      If[TrueQ[fileBytesTotal>OptionValue["ModeSwitchByteCount"]],
        CopyDirectoryFiles[src, targ, 
          getMinimalFileModSpec[restFiles, fullFNames]
          ],
        CopyDirectory[src, targ];
        PruneDirectoryFiles[targ, 
          StringTrim[
            getMinimalFileModSpec[remFiles, fullFNames, False],
            src
            ]
          ]
        ],
      If[True(*OptionValue@OverwriteTarget//TrueQ*),
        Quiet@DeleteDirectory[targ, DeleteContents->True];
        ];
      CopyDirectory[src, targ]
      ]
    ];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*getMinimalFileModSpec*)
getMinimalFileModSpec//Clear
getMinimalFileModSpec[
  restFiles_, 
  files_,
  pruneEmpties:True|False:True
  ]:=
  Module[
    {
      g1,
      g2,
      unchangedReduction,
      changedReduction,
      containedReduction,
      keys,
      changedKeys,
      missingDirs,
      baseSpec,
      deadDirs
      },
    (* 
            build associations mapping directories to contained files
            all the directories are keys in the Associations optimally 
            *)
    g1=Select[Not@*DirectoryQ]/@GroupBy[restFiles, DirectoryName];
    deadDirs=Complement[Select[restFiles, DirectoryQ], Keys@g1];
    g2=Select[Not@*DirectoryQ]/@GroupBy[files, DirectoryName];
    (* figures out which directories may be copied across wholesale *)
    unchangedReduction=
      AssociationMap[
        #[[1]]->
          If[
            !ListQ@g2[#[[1]]]||
              Length@Complement[Flatten@{g2[#[[1]]]}, #[[2]]]==0,
            #[[1]],
            #[[2]]
            ]&,
        g1
        ];
    (* find the directories that are in the full set but missing in the reduced set to prevent over reduction *)
    missingDirs=
      AssociationThread[
        Complement[Keys@g2, Keys@g1],
        0
        ];
    containedReduction=
      FixedPoint[
        KeySelect[
          (* 
                    checks if both the child *and* the parent are unchanged *and* 
                        if there's nothing missing vis-a-vis the original 
                    *)
          !StringQ@unchangedReduction[#]||
            !StringQ@unchangedReduction[DirectoryName[#]]||
            KeyExistsQ[missingDirs, DirectoryName[#]]||
            AnyTrue[Keys@missingDirs, StringStartsQ[DirectoryName[#]]]&
          ],
        unchangedReduction
        ];
    (* figure out which parent directories have changed *)
    keys=Keys@containedReduction;
    changedKeys=
      Select[keys, !AnyTrue[keys, StringMatchQ[#~~__]]&];
    baseSpec=
      Flatten@Values@
          KeyDrop[containedReduction, changedKeys];
    If[pruneEmpties,
      (* makes sure we're not pulling directories with no stuff to copy *)
      Select[
        !DirectoryQ[#]||
          Length@g1[#]>0||
          AnyTrue[
            Flatten@Values@KeySelect[g1, StringStartsQ[#]], 
            !DirectoryQ
            ]&
        ],
      Union[#, deadDirs]&
      ]@baseSpec
    ]
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*CopyDirectoryFiles*)
CopyDirectoryFiles[src_, targ_, files_]:=
  (
    MapThread[
      Which[
        DirectoryQ@#, 
          If[!DirectoryQ@DirectoryName[#2], 
            CreateDirectory[#2, CreateIntermediateDirectories->True]
            ];
          CopyDirectory[#, #2],
        FileExistsQ@#,
          If[!DirectoryQ@DirectoryName[#2], 
            CreateDirectory[DirectoryName[#2], CreateIntermediateDirectories->True]
            ];
          CopyFile[#, #2, OverwriteTarget->True]
        ]&,
      {
        files,
        Map[FileNameJoin@{targ, #}&, StringTrim[files, src]]
        }
      ];
      )
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PruneDirectoryFiles*)
PruneDirectoryFiles[targ_, files_]:=
  (
    Which[
      DirectoryQ@#, 
        DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents->True],
      FileExistsQ@#,
        DeleteFile[#]
      ]&/@Map[FileNameJoin@{targ, #}&, files];
    )
End[];
EndPackage[]
```

The real meat of all this is `getMinimalFileModSpec` which figures out what the minimal number of operations I need to do is.

It also performs pretty well:

```
PartialDirectoryCopy[
   FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
   "~/Desktop/test",
   "RemovePatterns" -> "*.nb"
   ] // AbsoluteTiming // First

1.59635

FileNames["*.nb", "~/Desktop/test", ∞] // Length

0

CopyDirectory[
   FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
   "~/Desktop/test2"
   ] // AbsoluteTiming // First

45.2356

FileNames["*.nb", "~/Desktop/test2", ∞] // Length

220
```

Anecdotally, this cut the build time for my paclets down from ~30 seconds to ~1 second.

Comment: Very useful. Should be a ResourceFunction. ;)

Comment: @wigg0t I’ll add it to the paclet rep but not worth putting in the function repo.